# True Center Vertical and Horizontal CSS Div

Tags: css, html, cross-browser, center

How is it possible to create a true center CSS div cross browser for example to use within a holding page?

I have tried this 2007 css trick -  **[How To Center an Object Exactly In The Center](http://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/)** but as you can see from my [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/P4RVD/) of the code its not 100% center.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="center">
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.center{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  border:5px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Why is `margin: 0 auto` not good enough?

Comment: @meagar: That only centers horizontally, not vertically.

Comment: Ah. Question really should indicate that the intention is to *vertically* center elements.

Comment: @meagar that is only for horozontal I need vertical as well

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That technique requires the element to have a fixed width and height. You are not setting the width and height. Based on your border and margins, to center it, the width would need to be 190 pixels and the height would need to be 90 pixels. Using `line-height` and `text-align` in combination with a fixed width and height makes the text and border centered. **[Try it.](http://jsfiddle.net/P4RVD/1/)**

**CSS**

```
.center{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 190px;
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  border:5px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do it with pure CSS:

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
div.centeredBlueBox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

It is important to give concrete (eg: `300px`) and not derived (like: `auto` or `30%`) values for `width` and `height`.

Comment: I think, this works best. It still works with resizing the content, without the need to recalc other sizes as well

Answer (score 3):

```
<div style='position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%; margin-left:(-)width_of_your_element/2px; margin-top:(-)height_of_your_element/2px'>
```

for example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div style='border:1px solid; width:200px; height:200px; position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%; margin-left:-100px; margin-top:-100px'>hallo</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's my solution:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; height: 100%;">
    <div style="position: relative; left: -50%; display: table; height: 100%;">
        <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
            //your content here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works in a lot of browsers. And there is no problem with content added after layout.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extra example with a height setter I created for IE vertical alignment. The extra span has a vertical-align:middle.

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow:hidden;
        text-align:center;
    }
    html, body{
        height: 100%;
    }
    #loginContainer {
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
        min-width:300px;
        text-align:left;
        height: 85%; /* vertical align not exact in the middle */
    }
    #loginContainer .label{
        width: 25%;
        float:left;
        white-space:nowrap;
        line-height:20px;
    }
    #loginContainer h2{
        border-bottom:2px solid #B4C3E1;
        border-width:0 0 3px;
        padding:2px 4px;
    }
    .mainHeader {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0; 
        text-align:center; 
        width:100%; 
        font-size:2em;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
    .detailsText {
        border-top:1px solid #F60;
        margin-top:5px;
        clear:both;
    }
    /* layout horizontal and vertical */
    .horizontalBox {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle; /* not seen by IE6-7 */
        height: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .verticalBox {
        padding: 55px 0 0 0; /* 55px height of logo */
    }
    .rightText {
        text-align:right;
    }
</style>
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
    #loginContainer {
        width:300px; /* minimum width */
    }
    .horizontalBox {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .verticalBox, .heightSetter {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: left;
        zoom:1;
    }
    .heightSetter {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .verticalBox {
        display: inline;
        height: 0;
    }
    .heightSetter {
        width: 1px;
    }
</style>    
<![endif]-->
<div class="mainHeader">This is the Header content</div>
<div id="loginContainer">
    <div class="horizontalBox">
        <div class="verticalBox">
            <h2>My header of the vertical box</h2>
            <p>My Content</p>
        </div>
        <span class="heightSetter"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at **[this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/)**; quite a clever article.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `display` type of the `DIV` to `table-cell`. Then you can use normal `vertical-align`, just like a `TD` element.

```
<div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; height: 200px;">
Centered Text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <style>
       .center { margin:auto; width:500px; background-color:green; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <p>Help me please</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.