# CSS Change Height

Tags: css

so I'm using the following code to change the contents of a div:
`document.getElementById("boxed").innerHTML = document.getElementById("aboutus").innerHTML;`

And the following is the CSS code behind the div "boxed":

```
.boxed
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
    min-height: 90%;
    height:auto;
    top:50%;
    background-color:#F5F5F5;
}
```

How can I keep the div centered vertically while at the same time allowing for vertical resizing based on the content within? I don't want to use overflow; I want the div itself to change size when I click a button that executes the Javascript code.

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: Block elements automatically adjust their height to fit the content. If you have vertical centering you'll need a css method that accounts for changing sizes, or just re-calc the position using javascript

Comment: This is a css question and this can be solved css only by using. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189625/true-center-vertical-and-horizontal-css-div